# Header image isn't appearing

Tags: html, css, header

The header image that I have isn't appearing in my site. I tried with clearfix but nothing. I tried to put width and height at image but nothing seems to work. Please help...

Here is JSFiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/bogdan9/eyzb9mkf/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
                <div id="container">
                <div id="JJO">
                        <h1>JJO</h1>
                        <h2>Juniors make IT work.</h2>
                        <h3>Hire and invest in highly skilled juniors now.</h3>

                        <a href="">Post Offer Now</a>

                </div>
                <div id="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Discounts</li>
                        <li>About Us</li>
                        <li>FAQ</li>
                        <li>Blog</li>
                    </ul>
                        <a href="">Login</a>
                </div>
              
            </div>

        </div>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family:manrope;
    
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px
}

#header{
    background: url('hero-image.png');
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    height:100%;
    width:100%
}


#JJO h1{
    font-size:45px;
    font-family:Source Sans Pro;
    color:white;
    margin:0px;
}

#container{
    width:1010px;
    margin:auto;
   
    
}

#JJO{
    float:left;
}

#nav{
    
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bogdan9/eyzb9mkf/2/

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow: hidden` on `header`

```
#header{
    background: url('https://i.ibb.co/SVgmsmw/hero-image.png');
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/L4jmtfqo/1/

Comment: Thank you, it works. But I also discovered that with clearfix : clear:both worked.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the background image display add below css.

```
html,body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

In order to make the percentage value to work, you need to set the parent element height.

Answer (score 0):

You can type both html and css in same page i have tried it and it is working fine with me

```
<style>
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family:manrope;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px
}

#header{
    background: url('hero-image.png');
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}


#JJO h1{
    font-size:45px;
    font-family:Source Sans Pro;
    color:white;
    margin:0px;
}

#container{
    width:1010px;
    margin:auto;
   
    
}

#JJO{
    float:left;
}

#nav{
    
}
</style>

<div id="header">
                <div id="container">
                <div id="JJO">
                        <h1>JJO</h1>
                        <h2>Juniors make IT work.</h2>
                        <h3>Hire and invest in highly skilled juniors now.</h3>

                        <a href="">Post Offer Now</a>
                </div>
                <div id="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Discounts</li>
                        <li>About Us</li>
                        <li>FAQ</li>
                        <li>Blog</li>
                    </ul>
                        <a href="">Login</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```